# Evaluate $\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{h}}}{h}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am looking for some hints to show that $\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{h}}}{h} = 0$.

I have tried rewriting

\begin{aligned}
\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{h}}}{h} &= \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{1}{he^{\frac{1}{h}}} \\
&= \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{h}+\ln h}}
\end{aligned}

but am struggling to show that as $h \to 0$, $\frac{1}{h} > -\ln h$, such that $e^{\frac{1}{h}+\ln h} \to \infty$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x = 1/h$, so that now you're interested in
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{1/x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{e^x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{e^x} = 0, $$
using l'Hôpital's in the second equality.

Comment: Thanks, Yuval! Very nice. Is there any way to show this without relying on l'Hôpital's rule though?

Comment: You can prove that $e^n \geq n^2$ for large enough integers $n$ by induction, and this implies that $e^{x+1} \geq x^2$ for large enough $x$ and so $x/e^x \leq 1/(ex)$ for large enough $x$. If you allow yourself to use the Taylor expansion of $e^x$, then we get $e^x > x^2/2$ directly for all $x \geq 0$.

Comment: The transition from integers to real numbers looks like it might take a bit of work. I would prefer to prove that $e^{x/2} \geq x$ for $x \geq 2$ by showing that $f(x) = e^{x/2} - x$ is increasing on that interval. Squaring both sides, you get $e^x \geq x^2$, so $x/e^x \leq 1/x$.

Comment: @user180040 The transition from integers to real numbers just uses monotonicity and the floor function, but your idea is indeed simpler.